# error while running entrypoint.sh file in docker-compose

Tags: docker

I am trying to dockerize my Flask application with Postgres database. I have an **entrypoint.sh** file that runs the migration files to create the tables and start the Supervisor monitor and control of the web server.

This is the code:

```
flask db upgrade

supervisord -c /config/supervisord.conf
```

and here is the ENTRYPOINT command in the **Dockerfile**:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

and in the **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
server:

container_name: server
restart: always
build: ./server
image: flask_app:v0.30
depends_on:
  - db
ports:
  - "5000:5000"
volumes:
  - ./server:/app
networks:
  - backend
entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
```

but when I ran the **docker-compose up** command I got:

> exec ./entrypoint.sh: exec format error

I've read that the problem happened because the image has been created in architecture but it is using a different architecture, but I couldn't found what is the solve of this problem. So, what how can I solve  this problem.

Comment: Show the **complete** `entrypoint.sh` file. Perhaps the #! line is wrong. The error message means that the executable has a wrong format; this could be the script file itself, or the binary from the #! line of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line at the top of your *entrypoint.sh*

```bash
#!/bin/sh

flask db upgrade

supervisord -c /config/supervisord.conf
```